# List Property in View Model is null when submitting grid MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, null, viewmodel

I have a grid with each row containing a check box.  If the check box is checked and the user hits the "Submit" button,  I want it to update the "Acknowledged" field in the database to "Y".  The problem that I'm having is that the record data is not getting passed to the controller during the post.

The "TransactionList" is coming in as null. The other properties are working correctly.  The TransactionList is where all of the record's data is stored (name, mtf, etc...)

My View Model which contains the Transaction List

```
namespace CCQAS.WebApp.Areas.Credentialing.Models
{
   public class CredTransactionsListViewModel
   {
     public List<CredTransactionsViewModel> TransactionList { get; set; }
     public string Status { get; set; }
     public string Action { get; set; }
     public bool Incoming { get; set; }
     public bool Outgoing { get; set; }
     public bool Primary { get; set; }
     public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
     public bool CanInsert { get; set; }
     public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
     public bool Search { get; set; }
  }
}
```

My View

```
@model CCQAS.WebApp.Areas.Credentialing.Models.CredTransactionsListViewModel
@using CCQAS.WebApp.Areas.Credentialing.Models
@using CCQAS.API.Model
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Transactions";
}
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">

        @Html.Partial("_SectionHelp", (string)ViewBag.HelpText)
        @ViewBag.Title
    </h3>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateAcknowledgement", "CredTransactions",       FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "cred-transactions", @role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Search)
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <fieldset>
        <th><b>Direction</b></th>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Incoming) Incoming
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Outgoing) Outgoing
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Primary) Primary
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <fieldset>
        <th><b>Status</b></th>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.Status, "UNACKNOWLEDGED") Unacknowledged
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Status, "ACKNOWLEDGED") Acknowledged
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Status, "") Both
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <fieldset>
        <th><b>Action</b></th>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.Action, "PCS") PCS
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Action, "ICTB") ICTB
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Action, "") All
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div></div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.Action, "DOCUMENTS") Update of Credentials Requested
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Action, "NONPRIMARYASSIGNMENT") Non-Primary Assignment Created
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Action, "CUSTODY") Custody Transfer
            </label>
        </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered data-table" id="myTable" name="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="hidden"></th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Acknowledged
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                From MTF
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                To MTF
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Primary MTF
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Action
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Initiated
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Provider Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                SSN
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Sender's Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                Sender's Phone
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
@foreach (CredTransactionsViewModel credTransactionsViewModel in Model.TransactionList)
    {
        long credProviderId = credTransactionsViewModel.CredProviderId;
        <tr>
            <td class="hidden"> @credTransactionsViewModel.ProviderTransactionId</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                @if (credTransactionsViewModel.AcknowledgedChar == "Y")
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" name=@credTransactionsViewModel.Acknowledged id="chkAcknowledged" checked="checked" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" name=@credTransactionsViewModel.Acknowledged id="chkAcknowledged" />
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @credTransactionsViewModel.FromUicTxt
            </td>
            <td>
                @credTransactionsViewModel.ToUicTxt
            </td>
            <td>
                @credTransactionsViewModel.PrimaryUicTxt
            </td>
            <td>
                @credTransactionsViewModel.Action
            </td>
            <td>
                @credTransactionsViewModel.Initiated
            </td>
            <td>
                @credTransactionsViewModel.ProviderFirst @credTransactionsViewModel.ProviderLast
            </td>
            <td>
                @credTransactionsViewModel.SSN
            </td>
            <td>
                @credTransactionsViewModel.SendersFirst @credTransactionsViewModel.SendersLast
            </td>
            <td>
                @credTransactionsViewModel.SendersPhone
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
 </table>
<div class="panel-footer text-center">
    <button type="submit" data-loading-text="Searching..." class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off">Search</button>
</div>
}
```

My Controller

```
using CCQAS.API.Abstractions.Service;
using CCQAS.API.Model;
using CCQAS.API.Model.Enums.FunctionalAreas;
using CCQAS.API.Model.Security.Enum;
using CCQAS.API.Web.UI;
using CCQAS.WebApp.Areas.Credentialing.Models;
using CCQAS.WebApp.Web.Mvc;
using CCQAS.WebApp.Web.Mvc.ActionFilters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CCQAS.WebApp.Areas.Credentialing.Controllers
{
public class CredTransactionsController : CredNavBaseController
{
    #region Private

    private ILookupService lookUpService;
    private ICredTransactionsService credTransactionsService;
    private IMtfService mtfService;

    #endregion Private

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Controller for Cred Transactions
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="credTransactionsService"></param>
    public CredTransactionsController(ILookupService lookUpService, ICredTransactionsService credTransactionsService, IMtfService mtfService)
    {
        this.lookUpService = lookUpService;
        this.credTransactionsService = credTransactionsService;
        this.mtfService = mtfService;
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    // GET: Credentialing/CredTransactions
    public ActionResult GetTransactionList(CredTransactionsListViewModel model)
    {
        string status = string.Empty;
        string action = string.Empty;
        string incomingFilter = string.Empty;
        string outgoingFilter = string.Empty;
        string primaryFilter = string.Empty;
        long mtfId = (long)this.CurrentUser.CurrentMtf.MtfId;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Permission permission = this.CurrentUser.GetPermission(ProviderArea.Transaction);
            //user mtf id
            //var model = new CredTransactionsListViewModel();

            if (model.Search != true)
            {
                 status = "UNACKNOWLEDGED";
                 action = "";
                 incomingFilter = "Y";
                 outgoingFilter = "";
                 primaryFilter = "";

                 model.Status = "UNACKNOWLEDGED";
                 model.Action = "";
                 model.Incoming = true;
                 model.Outgoing = false;
                 model.Primary = false;
            }
            else
            {
                status = model.Status;
                action = model.Action;
                if (model.Incoming == true)
                {
                    incomingFilter = "Y";
                }
                if (model.Outgoing == true)
                {
                    outgoingFilter = "Y";
                }
                if (model.Primary == true)
                {
                    primaryFilter = "";
                }
            }

            var credTransactionList = this.credTransactionsService.GetTransactionList(mtfId, status, action, incomingFilter, outgoingFilter, primaryFilter );
            model.TransactionList = (from credTransactions in credTransactionList
                                                                  select new CredTransactionsViewModel
                                                                  {
                                                                     ProviderTransactionId = credTransactions.ProviderTransactionId,
                                                                     CredAssignmentId = credTransactions.CredAssignmentId,
                                                                     CredProviderId = credTransactions.CredProviderId,
                                                                     CredCustodyId = credTransactions.CredCustodyId,
                                                                     ProviderFirst = credTransactions.ProviderFirst,
                                                                     ProviderLast = credTransactions.ProviderLast,
                                                                     ProviderName = credTransactions.ProviderName,
                                                                     SSN = credTransactions.SSN,
                                                                     FromMTF =credTransactions.FromMTF,
                                                                     ToMTF = credTransactions.ToMTF,
                                                                     PrimaryMTF = credTransactions.PrimaryMTF,
                                                                     FromUicTxt = credTransactions.FromUicTxt,
                                                                     ToUicTxt = credTransactions.ToUicTxt,
                                                                     PrimaryUicTxt = credTransactions.PrimaryUicTxt,
                                                                     Action = credTransactions.Action,
                                                                     AcknowledgedChar = credTransactions.AcknowledgedChar,
                                                                     Acknowledged = credTransactions.Acknowledged,
                                                                     AcknowledgedDate = credTransactions.AcknowledgedDate,
                                                                     AcknowledgedUserId = credTransactions.AcknowledgedUserId,
                                                                     Initiated = credTransactions.Initiated,
                                                                     SendersName = credTransactions.SendersName,
                                                                     SendersFirst = credTransactions.SendersFirst,
                                                                     SendersLast = credTransactions.SendersLast,
                                                                     SendersPhone = credTransactions.SendersPhone,
                                                                     InitiatedUserId = credTransactions.InitiatedUserId,
                                                                     ProviderTransactionTypeId = credTransactions.ProviderTransactionTypeId
                                                                  }
                                                                ).ToList();

            //var ReadOnly = this.IsCredReadOnly(permission);


            SetPageMessage(API.Web.UI.PageMessageType.Information, "Results showing last 6 months of history");
            return View(model);
        }
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UpdateAcknowledgement(CredTransactionsListViewModel model)
    {
        long userId = this.CurrentUser.UserId;
        long mtfId = (long)this.CurrentUser.CurrentMtf.MtfId;

        foreach (CredTransactionsViewModel credTransactionsViewModel in model.TransactionList.Where(m => m.Acknowledged ==true))
        {
            long providerTransactionId = credTransactionsViewModel.ProviderTransactionId;
            providerTransactionId = this.credTransactionsService.UpdateTransaction(providerTransactionId, userId, mtfId);
        }

        return View("GetTransactionList", model);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a little unclear why your `CredTransactionsViewModel` has a property `List<CredTransactionsViewModel>` and your model does not appear to contain a property named `Acknowledged` so I suspect there are some major problems with the design of your view model, but the reason that `TransactionList` is null is that you are not generating any controls relating to property `TransactionList`. Your `foreach` loop is just generating duplicate `ID` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes without indexers. You need to use a `for` loop (or a custom `EditorTemplate`).

Assuming `ProviderTransactionId` and `bool Acknowledged` in fact do exist, then it would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.TransactionList.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].ProviderTransactionId)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].Acknowledged)
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TransactionList[i].FromUicTxt)
  ....
}
```

Note that the html generated by the `for` loop is

```
<input name="TransactionList[0].ProviderTransactionId" ...>
<input name="TransactionList[1].ProviderTransactionId" ...>
```

which will correctly bind to your collection.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to rethink how you're doing this. Firstly the checkboxes will need a value otherwise how do you know which one is selected!? Next I'd create two html forms, one for the data at the top of the page, one for the list/table. Then create a new action in the controller that takes a list of integers as a parameter called the same as your checkbox id, post the second form to this action, lookup all of the records with the ids in the list and set field to Y. Easy!